# Random number generator, what's wrong with my approach/statistics? [JS]

Tags: javascript, random, statistics, sha512

First of all, what I want to know is if I am doing a systematic fault or am I messing up with the math, or do you have any ideas what could be wrong?

I was trying to write a little random number generator which numbers can be influenced / verified by the user (provably fair). The generated number is between 4096 and 65535. I simulated the function 100,000 times and get some strange statistics (Or am I thinking wrong??). 
Why is the chance that the number is under 8000 around ~50%. Shouldn't it be 50% around the middle of the number range (~30700)?

Here is the output of the simulation:

```
< 65536 : 100000 Times :100%
< 60000 : 91813 Times :91.813%
< 56000 : 86406 Times :86.406%
< 52000 : 81334 Times :81.334%
< 48000 : 76743 Times :76.743%
< 32768 : 62356 Times :62.356%
< 32000 : 61748 Times :61.748%
< 30719 : 60860 Times :60.86%
< 24000 : 56628 Times :56.628%
< 16000 : 52871 Times :52.871%
< 12000 : 51540 Times :51.54%
< 8000 : 50447 Times :50.447%
< 6000 : 36003 Times :36.003%
< 5096 : 21583 Times :21.583%
< 4608 : 11714 Times :11.714%
< 4250 : 3674 Times :3.674%
< 4100 : 100 Times :0.1%
< 4096 : 0 Times :0%
```

A little more details on the function I wrote:

I am generating two hashes. One is the userhash and the other is the serverhash. Both of these have a format like e.g.:

```
Server =3CDC3C8C97DEE62169B2C403BB2B6B501C1B0A0BD8015699B47DA67789C3F628
User   =CF27CC73E33E0AC1DA5239DE8DAF94044D89B8636DA90F4CE510E652C8AC7F54
```

(The Userhash, is generated by a unique ID. The Serverhash is generated by taking a random number (standard function: math.random() )and a timestamp and then HMAC-SHA-512 them.)

To get my "random" number, i take both (user and server) hashes and add them as hexadecimal numbers (userhash + serverhash = result). Then I take the result and cut everything except the first 4 digits. (E.g result = CF27)
After that, I convert it to decimal again.

The smallest number I can get from this should be in Hex 1000 (dec=4096), the biggest in Hex FFFF (dec=65535). That means my random number should be in a Range of 4096 - 65535.

Code Snippets:

```
//Function for getting a dec number from two hashes
function test_Rand(SERVER_SECRET, CLIENT_SECRET){

    var client_hash = require('crypto'),
        text = CLIENT_SECRET,
        key  = SERVER_SECRET

    // create hash
    var hash = client_hash.createHmac('sha512', key);
    hash.update(text);
    var clientRollAsHex = hash.digest('hex')
    var serverRollAsHex = SERVER_SECRET;
    //Add the numbers in Hex
    var roll_hex = addHex(clientRollAsHex, serverRollAsHex); 
    //Cut the hex String
    roll_hex = roll_hex.substring(0,4);
    // Make INT
    var roll_dec = parseInt(roll_hex, 16);
return roll_dec;

}

//Function for Hex-adding
function addHex(c1, c2) {
  var hexStr = (parseInt(c1, 16) + parseInt(c2, 16)).toString(16);
  while (hexStr.length < 6) { hexStr = '0' + hexStr; } // Zero pad.
  return hexStr;
}
```

The SERVER_SECRET comes from the following func.

```
var secret = function() {
    var r1 = Math.random()*10000000 + Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
    var r2 = Math.random()*1000000 + Math.floor(Date.now() / 2000);   //That does not make much sense
    var new_hash = require('crypto');
    var text = r1;
    var key  = r2;

    // create hahs
    var r_hash = new_hash.createHmac('sha512', key.toString());
    r_hash.update(text.toString());
    var retrn = r_hash.digest('hex');

    return retrn;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code of the random number generator please?

Comment: Thanks for reply, I edited my post an added some snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are taking the first four digits that you get a skewed result.

For 50% of the numbers you will get a result that is 65 digits long instead of 64, and the first digit is 1. For example adding the two numbers in your example:

```
   3CDC3C8C9...
   CF27CC73E...
= 10C0409007...
```

Taking the first four digits from the result gives you `10C0`. As you see from your result, there are a lot of numbers between `1000` (4096) and `1FFF` (8191). Most of those are numbers where the result is 65 digits instead of 64.

If you instead take any four digits at a specific position (counter from the right), for example the last four digits, you will get a pretty even distribution of numbers between `0000` and `FFFF`.

Comment: Thanks very much. You are absolutely right. Exactly this was the Problem!!

Answer (score 0):

A much simplified version of your design:

```
var a=Math.floor((Math.random() * 10));
var b=Math.floor((Math.random() * 10));
```

What is the range of `a+b`? **0-18**
Now take only the first digit of the result. Then 0-9 would still be their original value *but 10-18 becomes 1.

To get the result you want, you need to remove the first digit for cases 10-18.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will try to implement it.